# Remove array(s) from multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to be able to remove a specified amount of arrays from a multidimensional array where one value is the same in all of them. Example array I have:

```
array(
      array(1,'this'),
      array(2,'that'),
      array(1,'andthat')
)
```

So, for example, I would need to remove both arrays that have 1 as their first value.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is easier to read:

```
foreach($a as $i => $item)
    if($item[0]==1)
        unset($a[$i]);
```

where `$a` is the array, `$item` is the subarray, `$i` is the array index

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @gdscei Glad to head that!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do that.

```
$newArray = array_filter($arr, function($arr) { return $arr[0] != 1; });
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jQc0Ba).

Comment: how could I also filter on both the 1st and 2nd value?

Comment: @gdscei Use the `AND` operator in the function's body.

Comment: Actually, this is not exactly what I want. How would I make it remove x amount of arrays that have the conditions?

Comment: @gdscei Put a counter and code to increment it and return `true` after that counter has reached the limit.

Comment: Though doesn't this snippet just not display the things that I do not want? If so, how would I count it then?

Comment: @gdscei Sounds like you want to ask a new question. Feel free to link me to it.

Comment: Well... this was my original question. As I said in the OP, "...specified amount of arrays..."

Answer (score 0):

i tested this for prevent duplication of array, may this help you...

```
<?php
function func($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value)
  {
    if ( is_array($value) )
    {
      $result[$key] = func($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}
?>
```